# In AutoCompleteExtender how can I get/access the response on client side in order to redirect the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, autocompleteextender

Is there a way that `AutoCompleteExtender` of `AjaxControlToolkit` provide to access its response similar to ajax success function callback. Actually I am authenticating a call to webmethod. If a request is not authentic I am returning "500" from my webmethod, but if it is authentic request it should work verbatim.

Below is the markup of my `AutoCompleteExtender`

```
<ajx:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="txtsearch" 
    ServicePath="SearchWebService.asmx" 
    ServiceMethod="GetWorsList" 
    MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
    CompletionSetCount="20" 
    CompletionInterval="0" 
    EnableCaching="true" 
    CompletionListElementID="autocompleteList" >
</ajx:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Below is the code behind

```
[WebMethod]
public object GetWorsList(string prefixText)
{
    List<string> workNames = null;
    if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Header-Name"].ToString() !=
        HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Host.ToString())
    {        
        return "500";        
    }
    else
    {
        /*Success Part*/
    }    
}
```

I want to access the "500" value on my client side so that I can redirect to Logout.aspx page.

I tried `OnClientPopulated` as per [link 1](https://www.aspsnippets.com/questions/313967/Redirect-to-another-page-on-Ajax-AutoCompleteExtender-suggestion-selection-using-C-and-JavaScript-in-ASPNet/) and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091694/ajax-autocompleteextender-onclientpopulated-event-not-fire-in-firefox), but I am getting
`Parser Error Message: Type 'AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender' does not have a public property named 'OnClientPopulated'.`

Which left me no other option to ask question here.

**EDIT:**

The JS I tried is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function ResponseRedirecttoLogout(sender, args)
 {
            
    if (args.get_response() === "500") {
               
      window.location.href = 'logout.aspx';
    }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: You are missing `OnClientPopulated` in the `<ajx:AutoCompleteExtender` properties. Did you add it there? Also show the JS you tried.

Comment: @wazz I used `OnClientPopulated` but then it gives me Parse Error as I mentioned above, so, I exclude it from markup. Please check JS code for your reference.

Comment: There might be a version issue if you can't even put it on the page. (?) One thing I notice is that the method is supposed to return `string[]`. I don't know how strict that is. The signature: `public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count) { ... }`. See [here](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.net/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx).